# Iterate through JSON object array radio button

Tags: javascript, c#

A JSON like this is with me in a variable 
 var options_array  =

```
 [{"optionText":"1safsafs 1","optionDbId":1},{"optionText":"1safsafs 2","optionDbId":2},{"optionText":"1safsafs 3","optionDbId":3},{"optionText":" 1safsafs 4","optionDbId":4}]
```

I have to build a radio buttons with the items in this JSON and i am using the below code

```
             var choice_div = document.getElementById("choice_div");    

            var options_array = "[{\"optionText\":\"1safsafs 1\",\"optionDbId\":1},{\"optionText\":\"1safsafs 2\",\"optionDbId\":2},{\"optionText\":\"1safsafs 3\",\"optionDbId\":3},{\"optionText\":\" 1safsafs 4\",\"optionDbId\":4}]";

            console.log(options_array);
             console.log(options_array.length); //174 is coming here  instead of 4 

            for (i = 0; i < options_array.length; i++) {
                var _text = JSON.stringify(options_array[i].optionText);
                //console.log(_text);  //all values are coming as undefined 
                var _value = JSON.stringify(options_array[i].optionDbId);
                //console.log(_value);

                var option_entry = makeRadioButton("selectedoption", _value, _text);
                choice_div.appendChild(option_entry);
            }
        function makeRadioButton(name, value, text) {

            var label = document.createElement("label");
            var radio = document.createElement("input");
            radio.type = "radio";
            radio.name = name;
            radio.value = value;

            label.appendChild(radio);

            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            return label;
        }
```

but this code is adding 170 items to the DIV and i am getting radio button contents as undefined . Not able to spot the reason?
        I am expecting this to build 4 radio buttons with 4 options in it

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Object key is case sensitive. You've made some typos on your object keys.
`optiontext` -> `optionText`
`optiondbid` -> `optionDbId`

```js
for (i = 0; i < options_array.length; i++) {
    var _text = JSON.stringify(options_array[i].optionText);
    //console.log(_text);
    var _value = JSON.stringify(options_array[i].optionDbId);
    //console.log(_value);

    var option_entry = makeRadioButton("option" + i,_value, _text);
    choice_div.appendChild(option_entry);
}
```

## Update (11/10/2019)

The reason you are getting incorrect length is because you are logging JSON string length ( number of characters in your JSON string ) instead of the array length.

```js
var choice_div = document.getElementById("choice_div");    

// Get options_array as actual array instead of JSON string
var options_array = JSON.parse("[{\"optionText\":\"1safsafs 1\",\"optionDbId\":1},{\"optionText\":\"1safsafs 2\",\"optionDbId\":2},{\"optionText\":\"1safsafs 3\",\"optionDbId\":3},{\"optionText\":\" 1safsafs 4\",\"optionDbId\":4}]");

for (i = 0; i < options_array.length; i++) {
    // Dont need to stringify here
    var _text = options_array[i].optionText;
    var _value = options_array[i].optionDbId;

    var option_entry = makeRadioButton("selectedoption", _value, _text);
    choice_div.appendChild(option_entry);
}

function makeRadioButton(name, value, text) {
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = name;
    radio.value = value;

    label.appendChild(radio);

    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return label;
}
```

Comment: For me  the loop is working , but the values coming as undefined and i can see 170 as the length of options_array instead of 4

Comment: Perhaps you provided some wrong data ? In your JSON
```json
[{"optionText":"1safsafs 1","optionDbId":1},{"optionText":"1safsafs 2","optionDbId":2},{"optionText":"1safsafs 3","optionDbId":3},{"optionText":" 1safsafs 4","optionDbId":4}]
``` There's only four items in your array.

Comment: Ah, its because you are logging the JSON string's length which is the total number of characters in your string.

Answer (score 0):

you had some funny errors XD, first this the working one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var choice_div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    data = [{ "optionText": "1safsafs 1", "optionDbId": 1 }, { "optionText": "1safsafs 2", "optionDbId": 2 }, { "optionText": "1safsafs 3", "optionDbId": 3 }, { "optionText": " 1safsafs 4", "optionDbId": 4 }]
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
        var text = item.optionText;

        var value = item.optionDbId;
        console.log(value);
        var option_entry = makeRadioButton("option" + key, value, text);
        choice_div.appendChild(option_entry);
    });
});
function makeRadioButton(name, value, text) {

    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = name;
    radio.value = value;
    label.appendChild(radio);
    console.log("bot "+value);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return label;
}
```

then lets check what you did first you used JSON.stringify() with no reason , secondly you typed the json keys wrong thats was a little funny XD.

Comment: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected is showing while i am running this in edge